# Crossfade Images on Body

Tags: image, css, transition

Building a WordPress theme and trying to crossfade multiple background images on the body tag and not on a div!
I have been trying to use the tutorial here: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/ | Demo 3
with no success

Is it possibe to do without javascript and jquery and just use css only! Currently my Body css looks like this....

```
body {
    font-family: 'Arial', courier, sans-serif;
    background:url('ASSETS/bg2.jpg')no-repeat top left;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed
}
```

I do have another image to crossfade in my ASSETS folder called bg.jpg.

Comment: So where do you have the transition / animation...what triggers it?

Comment: so really I need to create a div that's 100% width and height then? not possible on the body at all hey?

Comment: You **could** do it on the body but it's not really clear what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: what/how are we crossfading here?

Comment: just 2 background images on the body is all!

Comment: @PhillipDews: and how/why/when are they transitioning?

Comment: Well put simply I have 2 images in my ASSETS folder and I am trying to achieve the same effect as demo 3 on that refrenced link in my original question @jbutler483

Comment: @PhillipDews: See my answer (I think it's what you're looking for)

Answer (score 2):

you could use a `keyframe` animation for this. Something like:

```css
body{
  height:100%;
  background:red;
  -webkit-animation: 9s fadeThis infinite;
  animation: 9s fadeThis infinite;
  }

@-webkit-keyframes fadeThis{
  0%{background:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/900/);}
  50%{background:url(http://lorempixel.com/900/900/);}
  100%{background:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/900/);}
  }
@keyframes fadeThis{
  0%{background:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/900/);}
  50%{background:url(http://lorempixel.com/900/900/);}
  100%{background:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/900/);}
  }
```

should crossfade for you.

---

See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) for more information on prefixing requirements.

Comment: Looks good and tried that buddy but alas it did not work for some reason. will try again! I ended us adding a div of 100% width and height and used that tutorial that I referenced above

Comment: @PhillipDews: what browser are you using? This should work fine (barr prefixing needed for firefox)

Comment: Ah I was using the firefox developer edition! why did I not think of that in the first place! what I'm using now I posted below! Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing! That tutorial that I referenced above originally still did not work so I tweaked it slightly...

**The CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: 'Arial', courier, sans-serif;
    background:url('ASSETS/bg.jpg')no-repeat top left;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

and then...

```
#cf {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#cf img {
    position:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    top:0; left:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out
}
@keyframes cfFadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    45% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    55% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
#cf > .top {
    animation-name:cfFadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

**The HTML**

```
<div id="cf">
<img class="top" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/ASSETS/bg2.jpg">
</div>
```

for those developing a WordPress theme like myself I added the opening CF div right after the **body tag** in my header file and of course closing that right before the ending **Body Tag** in the footer!

I then used z-index on the header, menu and content elements so tht the crossfade div is always the background! Also the css may need tweaking for mobile and tablet devices.